# Rendering a partial N times instead of for each item in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a set of attributes that belong to a product, e.g. `:name`, `:smalls`, `:mediums`, `:larges`, `:price`, etc.

Right `:smalls`, `:mediums`, and `:larges` are arrays of strings:

```
@products = [
  { :id => 1,
    :name     => 'Product 1',
    :description => 'description goes here',
    :smalls   => ['S'],
    :mediums  => ['M','M'],
    :larges   => ['L',],
    :price    => 50.0,
    :names_and_numbers => 'optional'
  }
]
```

The number of strings in each array determines the number of times the corresponding partial is rendered:

```
<div id="small-field-set">
<% product[:smalls].each do |small| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'small', :locals => { :product => product, :small => small } %>
<% end %>
</div>

<div id="medium-field-set">
<% product[:mediums].each do |medium| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'medium', :locals => { :product => product, :medium => medium } %>
<% end %>
</div>

<div id="large-field-set">
<% product[:larges].each do |large| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'large', :locals => { :product => product, :large => large } %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

How can I have a number, rather than the size the array, determine how many times the partials is rendered?

I tried doing this:

```
{ ...
  :smalls   => [1],
  :mediums  => [2],
  :larges   => [1],
  ...
}
```

But that did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this...

```
{ ...
  :smalls => [1],
  ...
}
```

...you still have an array: `[1]` is an array with one element, the integer `1` (just like `[1, 2]` is an array with two elements) . So first, you want to get rid of the arrays:

```
{ ...
  :smalls   => 1,
  :mediums  => 2,
  :larges   => 1,
  ...
}
```

For your view, when you use [`each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each) you're saying, "do this one time for each item in the array." Since you now have a number, not an array, you can use [`times`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-times) which, just like it sounds, means "do this N times":

```
<div id="small-field-set">
<% product[:smalls].times do %>
  <%= render :partial => 'small', :locals => { :product => product, :small => "S" } %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

P.S. I'm not sure what the purpose of `:small` in the `:locals` hash is. Since your partial is called `'small'` I'm guessing you don't need this, or can easily change your partial to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Why the array?

```
:smalls => 1,
```

Then

```
<% product[:smalls].times %>
  <%= render :partial => 'small', :locals => {:product => product } %>
<% end %>
```